# Old google keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, gboard

New emoji are not visible in the keyboard.

Hi all.  Please help me find the XML file that is responsible for displaying Emoji.  I use a Google keyboard modified for myself (I changed the position of the language switch and the emoji button).  In my version, only those emoticons that existed in the old version of iOS and Android are displayed.  The new keyboard (I can’t edit it because the files are encrypted) displays new emoticons (I checked, there are new emoticons in the system).  Where is the file that is responsible for displaying emoticons in the emoji section?  I'm posting photos with differences. I'm posting photos with differences.

**New keyboard**
[image: image1]

**Old keyboard (my version)**
[image: image2]